# Qt Creator with FFmpeg unresolved external

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, ffmpeg

I am using Qt Creator with FFmpeg in windows.
I built FFmpeg using vs2012 and specified the paths in project build environment's INCLUDE and LIB.
Yet I'm running into an error when i try to do this code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat\avformat.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    av_register_all();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This is the error:
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl av_register_all(void)" (?av_register_all@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you're linking your application against ffmpeg? Was it compiled with the same options as your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are linking cpp lib to C libs.

```
extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat\avformat.h"
}
```

Comment: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _av_register_all referenced in function _main